# How to find why ZendOPCache is restarting every 1 second?

Tags: php-5.6, opcache

ON a server, I've recently migrate from easyapache 3 to easyapache 4 and in the mean time I've update PHP to 5.6.

After this movement, I've notice that OPCache is restarting every 1 second with those settings

```
consistency checks  0
dups fix    false
enable  true
enable cli  true
enable file override    false
error log   no value
fast shutdown   true
force restart timeout   180
inherited hack  true
interned strings buffer 64
load comments   true
log verbosity level 1
max accelerated files   40000
max file size   0
max wasted percentage   0.4
memory consumption  536870912
optimization level  2147467263
preferred memory model  no value
protect memory  false
revalidate freq 60
revalidate path true
save comments   true
use cwd true
validate permission true
validate root   false
validate timestamps false
```

Does anyone have an idea why is doing it like this?

Answer (score 0):

Solution is to have PHP handler to have group permissions for folder. After resenting the permissions and change PHP handler to php-fpm then everything was ok.